# Counting clicks in a jButton array

Tags: java, for-loop, scope, jbutton

I'm trying to count the mouse clicks in an array of buttons but I am getting an error on my "click" variable that I don't quite understand:

"Local variable click defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

I'm guessing it has something to do with how I arranged my for-loop and the actionListener. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
int click = 0;

JButton buttonArray1 [] = {a1, a2, a3, a4,  b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4};

for (int d = 0; d < buttonArray1.length; d++) {
      buttonArray1[d].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      //add an action listener to the current button
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
       {
           click = click +1;

       }
      });
```

SOLVED:

```
   class Click{
                    int counter = 0 ;     
                    public void Click(){
                       counter++;
                    }
                    public int GetClick(){
                        return counter;

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define **click**  as a class variable...

the reason is that the **actionPerformed** is a callback interface implementation...

therfore you have 2 options

1. making the **click** final(makes no sense because then you can not change its value)
2. or declaring **click** as a class variable... (this is the way to go in your case)

Comment: How would I implement the class variable inside the loop?